# How to restore git submodules in VSO build task

Tags: git, build, azure-devops, git-submodules

I have one submodule(hosted in VSO) and I would like to build project in VSO and produce a nuget package. I dont know how to restore submodule so my project can build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the "Restore Submodules" box on the Repository tab.